# How should I setup my VSTS Builds for a solution which has dotnet core and non-core dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-pipelines

I've also logged this issue here :

[GitHub Issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/2420)

We have a ASP.NET Core API project running on Full Framework which depends on some non-core C# project in the same solution.

When I came to setup the CI build I setup:

GitVersion Task
NuGet Restore
DotNet Restore
Build

It fails in the DotNet Restore as the dependant non-core projects are not yet built. I tried creating two solution to split the build process between core and non-core and although the non-cure succeeds the core project does pick up the dll's and still fails with the same issue.

I've seen some issues logged on the dotnetcore-cli GitHub repo which could be related but nothing specifically for the issue I'm facing.

Comment: Are you able to build this from visual studio? (without any special treatments)

Comment: Yep, from VS this builds fine but not if you use MSBUILD / dotnet restore etc. We can replicate the problem from VSTS just in the command line.

Comment: have you installed (and updated) vs on the buildmachine?

Comment: any progress..?